# Help please identifying these components and their use

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors, identification, components

My first post, and I know very little. I have acquired a very old watch cleaning machine, its basically an electric motor that spins a small basket. I'd dearly love to get it working and have started to disassemble it and come across my first problem.

It appears that it has been modified at some time in its long life and the enclosed motor had these components stacked around it. I think, though I don't really know, that they are resistors? Can anyone confirm this and could anyone explain what they are there for?

Tjanks[image]

Comment: A photo of the components in question would be helpful.  As it is your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry. I posted it and found I forgot the picture. The answer, if I understand it correctly, is that they are resistors in series in an effort to slow the motor down. That would make sense, but would a potentiometer not do the same job?

Comment: They are wirewound resistors, ceramic coated. The labelled one is 200 Ohms 5%. They probably provide speed control for the motor. You haven't said what the problem is, but these probably aren't a problem.

Comment: More information would be helpful. What is the motor attached to, a picture would help even make and model number if possible. What voltage etc does it require. They are resistors that are used to limit the flow of current, but is about I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Those look like vitreous wirewound resistors, 200 ohm with a lower-case omega.  Kind of hard to eyeball the size but maybe 25 watt.  I doubt those are what's giving you trouble, unless you want to remove them entirely?  Power potentiometers aren't very common since their most common purpose is to serve as an adjustable voltage divider.  For a series pass element, their two-terminal cousins - rheostats - are much more common.  They're far more expensive than a fixed resistor of the same wattage since there are moving parts etc.  If you really want to get fancy with motor control, a more efficient way is to use PWM with a switching transistor.

Edit: now that I think about it more, they might be an issue if they are a retrofit.  Does the motor not turn on?

Comment: It's been in someone's garage for the past 20 odd years  I dare not power it up yet. It looks like a variable switch had been installed to change the resistance in steps. I was hoping to get rid of these resistors and replace with a variable resistor. Is that a viable option do you think?

Comment: Depends on the size of the motor.  Power rheostats can be expensive.  Otherwise there are pretty cheap motor controller boards you can get that take care of almost all the design of a PWM control system for you.